# Regular Expressions Help

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I need a little help with Regular Expressions.

The allowed operations are obviously + (union) , * (Kleene star) and concatenation.

I have to write Regex for the following 2 examples. I have tried a lot, but havn't succeed:

1. Write a Regex that receives all the words above $\Sigma = \{s,t\}$ which include at least two instances of the letter `t`, and don't include the subword `stt`.
2. Write a Regex that receives all the words above $\Sigma = \{s,t\}$ which include the subword `stts`, and don't include the subword `tss`.

I thought about these 2 alot. I understood that in 1 I have to somehow make sure that each 2 t's are seperated by s (except some exceptions). the same trick should be implemented in 2 too.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Hint: if it can't contain the subword `stt`, then what are the eligible subwords it can contain? Think about the acceptable subwords and their patterns, then construct a pattern to match all of them...

Comment: @Newb Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: Exactly the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750591/formal-languages-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

For 1, one must be carefiul to include variants starting with at least two $t$:
`ttt*(s+st)*`
Then there are the variants starting with one $t$: `tss*t(s+st)*`
And those starting with no $t$: `ss*tss*t(s+st)*`. These can be nicely combined into `(tt*+s*tss*)t(s+st)*`, a pattern one might not have guessed out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use $|$ for [alternation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_%28formal_language_theory%29) (I think this is more standard than $+$).

---

For your first example, if you have a `tt` in your expression, you won't be able to have any `s` before it. I think this works:

$$(t)^*t(s)^*t(st\,|\,s)^*$$

---

In the second problem, you need an `stts`, and the strings on the right cannot start with an `s` and cannot have two consecutive `s`'s. The strings on the left can either be completely `s` or not have consecutive `s`'s. I think this covers all of the possibilities:

$$\left((t\,|\,st)^*\,|\,(s)^*\right)stts(t\,|\,ts)^*$$

Comment: This is wrong.  The first language should include `tst`, which contains two instances of the letter `t` and does not include the subword `stt`.  Your expression does not include this word.

Comment: @MJD Thanks about the correction.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, I think I fixed it now ... ?